# How to write a python program to read an unspecified number of scores and determines how many scores are above, equal, and below to average?

Tags: python

How to write a python program to read an unspecified number of scores and determines how many scores are above, equal, and below to average?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: Show your progress. Add some code you wrote

Comment: Made an example. If it is necessary on your data, then  need to see them first.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(50)# 1
average = np.mean(a)#2
u = (a > average).sum()#3
equally = (a == average).sum()#4
d = (a < average).sum()#5
print('array of 50 values', a)#6
print('average', average)#6
print('Count the number above the average', u)#6
print('Count the amount that is equal to the average', equally)#6
print('Count the number below the average', d)#6
```

1. An array of 50 random elements is created.
2. calculate the average value of these 50 elements.
3. Count the number above the average.
4. Count the amount that is equal to the average.
5. Count the number below the average.
6. Output all values.

Comment: Hello everyone. Updated the message. If something is not clear, write.